# how to navigate from one tab to other by clicking on a hyperlink using jquery ui tabs

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Could any one help me on how to navigate from first tab to second tab by clicking a hyperlink in first tab using JQUERY UI tabs?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#...select_a_tab_from_a_text_link_instead_of_clicking_a_tab_itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer the [jQuery UI Tabs documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-select) for your problem, its very well mentioned

```
var $tabs = $('#example').tabs(); // first tab selected

$('#my-text-link').click(function() { // bind click event to link
    $tabs.tabs('select', 2); // switch to third tab
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between tabs freely by following the indexes using select [method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-select). 
An example:

```
$("#tabs").tabs('select', 1);
```

Attach this snippet to the click handler of the link on the content of first tabs.

**Example:**

For a link like this:

```
<a href="some.html" id="nextTab">Go to Next Tab</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#nextTab").click(function() {
     $("#tabs").tabs('select', 1);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help, and in order to stay on the selected tab we have to put return false also at the end.

Comment: Another issue which i am facing is that for a full postback on a tab i used cookie but the problem is even after closing the page and openning back the previously selected tab is coming i want the DEFAULT tab to be displayed, could anyone help in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the select method http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-select

Answer (score 0):

Let say you initialized your tab like:

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
```

You can select / navigate to different tab via programming like:

```
$('#tabs').tabs('select', index);
// Where index start from 0, 
// 0 for the first tab, 1 for the second, and 2 for the third and so on
```

Let say you have a link in first tab,
To navigate to 2nd tab on click, you can do something like this:

```
$('#link_in_first_tab').click(function (event) {
  $('#tabs').tabs('select', 1);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

More API usage please refer to jQUery UI page:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/